# Shall Android AudioRecorder read all the sample or just a fraction?

Tags: android, buffer-overflow, android-audiorecord

This question is somehow related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700070/android-audiorecorder-how-to-reduce-min-read-buffer-size/38004634#38004634.

When I used AudioRecorder to implemente a VOIP application, I find that getMinBufferSize() returns 1024 for 8000Hz, mono, 16Bit settings which is 64ms in time.

1. However I need to read a 20ms each time for feeding the audio encoder. So can I use the read(ByteBuffer buf, int size) method with size=20*8*2=320, or should I read out all the buffer with size=getMinBufferSize?
2. What will happenned if I cannot read all the samples in 64ms, will some samples be missing? Or the is buffer a circular array, so I can still read the correct samples until the buffer overflows?